# Javascript new Date gives me wrong date

Tags: javascript, date

[image]

I'm giving the right Params but is giving me yesterday's Date, I still haven't detected the error.

Answer (score 1):

`new Date("2022-6-20").toUTCString()` Worked for me. I needed to use my current Time Zone

Comment: `new Date("2022-6-20").toUTCString()` produces an invalid Date in Safari at least. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) The timestamp is not a supported format so might be parsed as local, UTC or junk.